# Nginx - Have a main proxy, proxying requests to two other Nginxes

Tags: nginx

I need to have a main page that links to two other applications:

main.com will have an index page at "/" and should load application "A" at main.com/a as well as application "B" at main.com/b.

Both applications have a nginx.

Main Nginx:

```
   server {
        server_name nginx_server;

        location / {
            root ./;
            index index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /a/ {
            proxy_pass https://a.com/;
        }

        location /b/ {
            proxy_pass https://b.com/;
        }

    }
```

"A" and "B" application Nginx:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name nginx_server;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }

  location /api {
     proxy_pass http://mybackend;
  }
```

Going straight to a.com and b.com, it all works, but trying main.com/a or main.com/b doesn't.

The issue is that the frontend application (for example, "A", which is an Angular app) tries to load it's resources from the wrong url.

*main.com/a* loads a's index.html file, that has `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">` which in turn tries to load *main.com/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css* instead of *main.com/**a**/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css*.

Is this design possible?

Comment: Are you trying to proxy or redirect? Since you are using `proxy_pass` I'm guessing you want to proxy? If so, you are failing to proxy the "assets" folder and would need to in order to make this work. And furthermore, you might have duplicate "assets" folders, one for each of a.com and b.com, if that's how you structured things.

Comment: @ChrisZacharias To be honest, I am kind of new using NGINX. I want to keep the browser url as main.com/a and main.com/b, but also want to be able to navigate to a.com and b.com without any issues.
The assets folder indeed exists in both a and b (both are angular apps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out the issue.

Both A and B (angular applications) index.html files had this tag: `<base href="/">` which made every other "href" point to the root url *main.com*.

Changing it to `<base href="">` solved the issue.